# mp3 share via whatsapp (this file is not supported) error

Tags: java, android

when i click created share button i took the file is not supported error 
i did try a lot of answers about this issue in stackoverflow but i cannot access success
thank you so much aldready

```
Button btnShare;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnShare=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    btnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            File f=new File("R.raw.sound3");
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://"+f.getAbsolutePath());
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            share.setType("audio/*");
            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share audio File"));         

        }
    });



}
```

}

manifest permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need to do. Firstly check if you have granted permission and check if your raw data in external storage.Let's give example :

We have a simple button on main xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Paylas" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Check if you have permisson :

```java
 public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v("","Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.v("","Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v("","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.v("","Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
            //resume tasks needing this permission
        }
    }
```

Copy your raw data into external storage :

```java
 private String copyFiletoExternalStorage(int resourceId, String resourceName){
        String pathSDCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/" + resourceName;
        try{
            InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            out = new FileOutputStream(pathSDCard);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;
            try {
                while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buff, 0, read);
                }
            } finally {
                in.close();
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pathSDCard;
    }
```

and the main code should be like this :

```
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isStoragePermissionGranted()) {
                String rout = copyFiletoExternalStorage(R.raw.guitar,"guitar.mp3");
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(rout);
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("audio/*");
                share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
                try {
                    startActivity(share);
                }catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please, install Whatsapp", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Also may you want to check full source code here is [github](https://github.com/barankaraboga/androidsharemp3onwhatsapp)

Comment: thank you so much man, you're awesome this is were very helpful, appreciate it dude, take care!